# How can I map two arrays into one Perl hash?

Tags: perl

I am new to perl. I need to understand how can I map one array (as keys) to another (as values) to result in a hash using foreach loop:

```
@one = ("A", "B", "C");
@two = ("a", "b", "c");
```

I wrote the following code but it does not work when I slice the hash??

```
%hash;
foreach $i (one) {
  print $i, "=>" , $ii = shift @two, "\n"
}
```

Comment: You want the keys to be the elements of `@one` and the values the corresponding elements of `@two`?

Comment: To use your approach, you _could_ iterate over the index (of equal-length arrays) and add hash elements one at a time: `for my $i (0..$#one) { $hash{$one[$i]} = $two[$i] }`.  But there are much better ways, like in @Shawn's answer.

Comment: Please _always_ have `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the beginning of programs.

Comment: You wanted ```foreach $i (@one) {``` <== mind the @

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming the answer to my question in the comment is "yes", here's a couple of approaches.

Given:

```
my @one = qw/A B C/;
my @two = qw/1 2 3/;
```

Using hash slices:

```
my %hash;
@hash{@one} = @two;
```

Using the [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) module from CPAN:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw/zip/;
my %hash = zip @one, @two;
```